# javascript not working correctly when loading page from link_to()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

my problem is pretty particular as it is very specific.
My `rails app` has a `sidebar` that serves as navigation between the different pages and whenever I load a page using the `nav links` generated inside this `sidebar`, the page loaded has very peculiar `javascript`.

For example, my `ajax` calls only work partially as the `controller` does save the data but the associated `ajax:success` is not getting called and so the save message does not get printed.

The weirdest thing is that everything works fine if the same page is loaded by directly typing the address in the navigation bar or if I reload the page, so the problem seem to be the nav link generated by `link_to()`

Some code to illustrate.

_side_navbar.html.erb

```
<%= nav_link("", edit_company_path(@company)) %>
<%= nav_link("", edit_fiscal_path(@company.fiscal))%>
<%= nav_link("", controller: 'socials', action: 'edit')%>
```

application_helper.rb

```
def nav_link(text, link) #allows me to apply .active bootstrap class to current link in the sidebar
 class_name = current_page?(link) ? "list-group-item-info" : nil
 link_to text, link, class: "list-group-item #{class_name}"
end
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@company, {remote: true, html: {class: "update-form"}}) do |company_form| %> #ajax form
...
<%= submit_tag('Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary') %>
```

companies_controller.rb

```
def update
 if (@company.update(company_params))
  render json: AJAX_SUCCESS_MESSAGE.to_json, status: 200 #works as the object is succesfully updated in the db.
 else
  response = {message: @company.errors.full_messages, models: @company.errors.keys}
  render json: response, status: 422
 end
end
```

utils.coffee

```
$ ->
 $('.update-form').on 'ajax:success', (event, data, status, xhr) ->
  console.log "here" #does not get printed to the browser console
  #successDiv = createDiv("alert-success")
  #successDiv.append xhr.responseJSON
 $('.update-form').on 'ajax:error', (event, xhr, status, error) ->
  console.log "here" #doesn't work either
  #errorDiv = createDiv("alert-danger")
  #$.each xhr.responseJSON.message, (index, value)->
   #errorDiv.append value + '. '
  #addDivContext(xhr.responseJSON.models)
```

So as said above, evrything works well beside the `ajax:success` that apparently does get called since no message is printed in the browser console.
I really have no idea on how to debug that, so thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Trying adding `.on 'ajax:error'` or `.on 'ajax:done'` and `console.log()` there to see what's going on. Also, I think your function will bug out and crash if `createDiv("alert-success")` fails.

Comment: I'm already doing a `ajax:error`, it doesn't work either. Edited original post.

Comment: I know it might sound silly, but try simplifying your `form_for`. Had some pretty quiet issues in the past for putting many parentheses and brackets. Try `form_for(@company, remote: true, class: "update-form")`.

Comment: your syntax only works for `submit_tag`, I have to use `html:{}` with `form_for`

Comment: Hmm, are you using Turbolinks?

Comment: If so, try replacing `$ ->` with `$(document).on 'ready page:change', ->` to bind on Turbolink redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume either `.update-form` is not present when the dom is ready, or you are using turbolinks, in which case your js-code is not executed again.

A simple work-around could be something like this

```
$ -> 
  $(document).on 'ajax:success', '.update-form', (event, data, status, xhr) ->
    console.log "received!"
```

If you are using turbolinks, the cleanest way is to use

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', -> 
  $('.update-form').on 'ajax:success', (event, data, status, xhr) ->
    console.log "here"
```

instead of the simple `$ ->`

Comment: You were rigth, it working as intended with the `$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->`, thanks (doesn't explain me why loading the page by typing the address in the browser navigation bar worked but loading from nav links "bugged" the DOM but well)
`Turbolinks` are enabled by default with `rails 5.0` it seems as I did not put them myself and they are used in my app and I barely understand what they do, if you don't mind explaining the how and why too, thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you reload the page, it will do a full reload, so the `$ ->` will work (a document ready event is triggered). When following links, it will only partially reload the page, because of turbolinks, so it will only trigger the `page:load` event.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your `submit_tag` be `company_form.submit`?

And for Turbolinks, try replacing $ -> with $(document).on 'ready page:change', -> to bind on Turbolink redirects.

Comment: Yeah you're right :) Doesn't fix my problem tho but thanks

Answer (score 0):

companies_controller.rb

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
   if (@company.update(company_params))
    format.js
   else
    response = {message: @company.errors.full_messages, models: @company.errors.keys}
    format.json {render json: response, status: 422}
   end
 end
end
```

add: `update.js.erb` in the same folder where `edit.html.erb` located

```
console.log("Update.js.erb file Updated");

$('nav').after("<div class='alert alert-success'> Successfully Updated </div>");
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@company, {remote: true, html: {class: "update-form"}}) do |company_form| %> #ajax form
...
<%= submit_tag('Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary') %>
```